# What part of speech is "tranquilized" after keep?

Tags: parts-of-speech

I read the following sentence in a comic book:

> *keep her tranquilized*

What will be tranquilized here? Is it a past participle or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Keep** is the verb.  **Her** is the direct object.  **Tranquilized** is the adjective describing the direct object.

"her" is what is being tranquilized.

This sentence uses an implied subject.  "You" is the implied subject, so the sentence is identical to

```
You keep her tranquilized.
```

You can tell if an implied subject is present by there not being a subject before the verb.  There are exceptions for questions, where the "question word" verb is permitted before the subject, but this is not a question (by the lack of the question mark and "question" word (Will, did, can, ...).

Comment: tnanks a lof for you help :)

Comment: @Alpharius You are welcome.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

It is an adjective or a past participle.

There really isn't enough context in such a short sentence that could allow us to decide, and the past participle means the same as an adjective formed from the past participle, so the "label" doesn't really matter.

The woman ("her") has been tranquillized. And the imperative sentence is a command to someone to make sure that she stays tranquillized.  It should be obvious in the book who "her" refers to.

Comment: thank you  for help :)